# InputCheckBox - check the box based on a condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

The goal here is to have a checkbox bound to a bool variable of an object. Now when we check the box it should give a confirmation pop up and if I select 'yes' it should go ahead with the procedure, but if I select 'no' then it should come back to the original state. So, for the demo I implemented a confirm box and there I am checking the condition.

**Razor file:**

```xml
<InputCheckbox @bind-Value="@product.IsAssociated" @oninput="(e)=>AssociateProducts(e,product)"/>
```

**Code:**

```cs
public async void AssociateProducts(ChangeEventArgs e,Product product)
{
   bool confirmed = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", "Are you sure?");
   if (confirmed)
   {
      //normal procedure
   }
   else
   {     
       //this code isn't changing the state  
       product.IsAssociated = false;
       StateHasChanged();
   }
}
```

So when we give 'No' as our answer, this code executes:

```cs
   else
   {     
       //this code isn't changing the state  
       product.IsAssociated = false;
       StateHasChanged();
   }
```

I want that the checkbox to be unchecked after this.
This doesn't change the state of our product and it is 'TRUE' only when I printed it and checked.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide your js code?

Comment: You should handle this entirely in JavaScript.

Comment: You can also do it entirely in C# and Blazor.   Are you using a css framework?  If so which one?  I could give you an answer in Bootstrap but you may not be using that.

Comment: @Chetan, you might as well tell him to use Angular (JS only)

Comment: *When we check the box  it should give a confirmation pop* doesn't say anything about what happens when the box is unchecked. Should the confirmation show when the box is UNchecked?

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. I am using .net 6 currently. Yes the confirmation will come up in any case. I'll respond to the confirmation if I really want to check/uncheck the box. For example : I have an unchecked box, if I check it, there should be a pop up and if I say 'No' to it then the checkbox should remain as unticked. In my case it gets ticked after saying 'no'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my second answer... This is how you have to code and use logics

Either use the `change` event or the `input` event, but not both. When you do this:

```
    `@bind-Value="@product.IsAssociated" @oninput=" 
                               (e)=>AssociateProducts(e,product)"`
```

You are using two events while you can and should use a single event: `change`

Do use `async Task` instead of `async void`

Most importantly, your logics is faulty: When you run the app for the first time and `product.IsAssociated` is false. The user checks the checkbox, he clicks OK as a geture of confirmation. Suppose he decided after this action to cancel his previous selection. In order to do that he should click on the checked checkbox in order to undo the previous action. Your code does not do that, and does not take into account, clicking on the "Cancel" button.

```
@page "/"

 @inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
 <EditForm Model="product">
    <InputCheckbox ValueExpression="@( () => product.IsAssociated )" 
                   Value="@product.IsAssociated" 
                   ValueChanged="@( (bool args) => AssociateProducts(args, product) )"/>
</EditForm>

<div>product.IsAssociated: @product.IsAssociated</div>
@code { 

    private Product product = new Product { ID = 1, Name = "Product1", IsAssociated = false };

    public async Task AssociateProducts(bool args, Product product)
    {
        bool confirmed = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>( "confirm", new [] { "Are you sure?" });

        if (confirmed && !product.IsAssociated)
        {
             product.IsAssociated = true;
        }
        else if(confirmed && product.IsAssociated)
        {
             product.IsAssociated = false;
            
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsAssociated { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Understood the logic and is working fine for me

Answer (score 1):

I just add `EditForm` and it works successfully.

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime


<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>


<EditForm Model="@product">
    <InputCheckbox @bind-Value="@product.IsAssociated" @oninput="(e)=>AssociateProducts(e,product)"/>
</EditForm>



@code{

    public Product product { get; set; } = new Product();

    public async void AssociateProducts(ChangeEventArgs e,Product product)
    {
       bool confirmed = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", "Are you sure?");
       if (confirmed)
       {
          //normal procedure
       }
       else
       {     
           //this code isn't changing the state  
           product.IsAssociated = false;
           StateHasChanged();
       }
    }
}
```

**Demo**

[image]

**I hope it is what you expect.**

Comment: *I hope it is what you expect* - it isn't what I would expect from a logical UI

Comment: Yes I want exactly this and I also had it inside the Editform. Can you please try a case where the checkbox isn't ticked and when you check it, on the pop up you do 'cancel'. It should ideally be unticked after that as well. For me this isn't working.